# Batch, If statement is not working when I don't type anything

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a program in batch that uses if to test for an invalid choice. But it gives an error when I don't type anything and just press enter

Here is an example:

```
:start
echo 1+1=
set /p "ans=>"

if %ans% == 2 goto correct
echo wrong
goto start

:correct
echo correct
pause
```

When I type nothing it says "goto was Unexpected at this time" then it exits

If there is anyone that know how to fix this that would be great.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but there's a good chance that it's because `start` is a keyword in batch. Try calling it something else.

Comment: @SomethingDark: while `start` is the equivalent of a Unix shell _builtin_, but it's perfectly fine to use it as a _label_ name in a batch file.

Comment: The critical issue here is that `set /p` will leave the target variable (`ans`) **unchanged** if you simply press the `enter` key. Since `ans` has no value at the time the `set/p` is executed, it will have no value after, so the `if` is resolved to `if == 2 goto...` which `cmd` can't understand. Using quotes as suggested by Monacraft is the standard solution. You cn use this characteristic to allow a default value. if you `set ans=2` before your `set/p` then if the user presses just `enter`, `ans` will have an unchanged value (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent blank input ruining your code you need to use `"`'s in if statements:

```
:start
echo 1+1=
set /p "ans=>"

if "%ans%" EQU "2" goto correct
echo wrong
goto :start

:correct
echo correct
pause
```

Which should work